# Nodejs express server goes down when some error occur

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express as my Node.js web framework with MongoDB as persistence layer. When I run the server with 'node app.js' command, and occasionally some error occur such as mongoose error or imagemagick error, the hole node process will die and not available from browser. I used Express' error handler but this is still happening. Can someone help?

Comment: What version of node are you using? I got around this using the clusters package and the process.on('death') message. Look at the example code for clusters on the node.js website

Comment: @zhangxuefeng post this as an answer and then accept it - that way, other people with the same problem will see that there is a solution

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999373/how-do-i-prevent-node-js-from-crashing-try-catch-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clusters.on('death', function(worker) {
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.error(err);
  console.log("Node NOT Exiting...");
});
```