# Error from nodejs server thrown not being passed back to AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I have the following `AJAX` that will send the entered data to the node server and the `controller` will check whether such data exist in the database or not.
If I do enter the data correctly, then everything is working fine.

However, I tried enter anything that the database does not have and it immediately throw an error, causing the server to stop. The error said that I did not handle the event, so I tried with `res.json(err)` in the `controller` instead of `throw new Error`, hoping that the error will be passed back to AJAX under the `error` key, but it is still not working. The error still gets thrown and the node server terminate itself.

I would like the server to continue and alert to the user that the data that was entered is not in the database but I have no idea why my approach is not correct.
I was thinking of using this SO thread if I'm able to get the error message back first from server side.
[jQuery Ajax error handling, show custom exception messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages)

To solve the server from stopping, I used the code in `app.js` that was referred from this link

[How do I prevent node.js from crashing? try-catch doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999373/how-do-i-prevent-node-js-from-crashing-try-catch-doesnt-work)

I'm not sure whether should I use the accepted answer for my case.

```
function createProduct(inputval){
    let inputAction = window.location.pathname;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  inputAction,
        data: {order: inputval.split('-')[0].trim(), lot: inputval.split('-')[1].substring(0,5)},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#product').val('');
            //Another function to add HTML 
            display(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("XHR" + jqXHR)
            console.log("Status" + textStatus)
            console.log(errorThrown)
        }
     });
}
```

> Controller File

```
exports.createProduct = function (req, res) {

    db.Product.findOne({ "order": req.body.order, "lot": req.body.lot }).exec(function (err, product) {
        if (!product || err){
              throw new Error("The product entered returns null");
        }
        res.json(product);
  });
};
```

> Main File: `app.js`

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.log("Node NOT Exiting...");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out thanks to feedback from other community, so I thought I would just share it here. It's so simple and silly me for neglecting such statement.

> First, the code in `app.js` can just be removed.
>
> Second, based on the answer given by @Milad Aghamohammadi. Instead of just:

```
res.status(500).end();
```

Use:

```
return res.status(500).json({err: "Server error"});
```

This way, the error is able to be handled by the AJAX error function and the node server will not be terminated from the event loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should use correct status code for your response. I suggest change your controller like below snippet

```
exports.createProduct = function (req, res) {

    db.Product.findOne({ "order": req.body.order, "lot": req.body.lot }).exec(function (err, product) {
        if (err){
            res.status(500).end();//means internal server error
        } else if (!product) {
            res.status(404).end();//means product not found
        } else {
            res.json(product);
        }
    });
};
```