# Firestore realtime listener error unhandled in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, error-handling, google-cloud-firestore

I have made a function that I am exporting using node.js called `return_match_uid`. I am importing the function in another express routing file and am using `async` `await`, with `try` and `catch` to handle the error. But somehow, the errors produced by `return_match_uid` always slip and are unhandled, even though I am using the error handling for the realtime listener recommended by Firestore doc

Here is the function:

```
exports.return_match_uid = function return_match_uid() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsub = db.collection('cities').onSnapshot(() => {
      throw ("matching algo error");
      resolve();
      unsub();
    }, err => {
       console.log(err);
    })
  })
})
```

In another express router file, I am calling the function:

```
const Router = require('express').Router;
const router = new Router();
const {return_match_uid} = require("./match_algo");

router.get('/match', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var match_user = await return_match_uid(req.query.data, req.query.rejected);
    res.send(match_user);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log("Matching algorithm return error: " + error);
  }
})
```

The error I am throwing inside the function: `matching algo error` do not get caught by either the `err => {console.log(err);})` in the function nor the `try` `catch` block in the router. It slips and causes my app to crash. It shows the following error:

```
        throw "matching algo error!";
        ^
matching algo error!
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I am throwing an error inside `matching algo error` because I have some other codes in there, and there is a possibility that it produces an error. If it does, I would like to make sure that it gets handled properly.

Comment: What nodejs version are you using? there is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999373/how-do-i-prevent-node-js-from-crashing-try-catch-doesnt-work) that explains how to workaround this issue.

Comment: node.js 12.17.0